# Activity time & duration tracker

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

This is my first attempt at creating a simple Python tool that tracks the time of certain activities retrieved from a database. After stopping the timer, this tool writes the duration of the activity into the database.

Can you please provide me some tricks to make this code more Pythonic?

**objects.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Project:
    '''Class that holds the projects'''
    projects = []

    def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
            self.tasks = []
            type(self).projects.append(self)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    @property
    def name(self):
            return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
            if not name:
                    raise ValueError(_('You need to specify a value!'))
            self._name = name

    def add_task(self, task):
            if (task not in self.tasks):
                    self.tasks.append(task)

    def get_tasks(self):
            return self.tasks

    @staticmethod
    def get_project_by_name(name):
            for project in Project.projects:
                    if name == project.name:
                            return project

class Task:
    '''A task for a project'''
    def __init__(self, id, name):
            self.id = id
            self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
            return '{0}:{1}'.format(self.id, self.name)

    def __eq__(self, other):
            return self.id == other.id and self.name == other.name

    @property
    def name(self):
            return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
            if not name:
                    raise ValueError(_('You need to specify a value!'))
            self._name = name


class Entry:
    '''A timesheet entry that contains the task, the date and the time spent'''
    def __init__(self, task, date, duration):
            self.task = task
            self.date = date
            self.time_in_minutes = self._get_duration_in_minutes(duration)

    def __str__(self):
            return '{0}|{1}|{2}'.format(self.date, self.task, self.time_in_minutes)

    def _get_duration_in_minutes(self, duration):
            hours, minutes = duration.split(':')
            return int(hours) * 60 + int(minutes)
```

### database.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sqlite3
from objects import Project, Task

class KronosDatabase():
    _db_connection = None
    _db_cursor = None

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._db_connection = sqlite3.connect(filename)
        self._db_cursor = self._db_connection.cursor()

    def __del__(self):
        self._db_connection.close()

    def insert_entry(self, entry):
        self._db_cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Entry(task, time_in_minutes, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)''', (entry.task, entry.time_in_minutes, entry.date) )
        self._db_connection.commit()

    def get_projects(self):
        query =  self._db_cursor.execute('''SELECT name FROM Project''').fetchall()

        for result in query:
            Project(result[0])

    def get_tasks_for_project(self, project_name):
        query = self._db_cursor.execute('''SELECT id, name FROM  Task WHERE project = ?''', (project_name,) ).fetchall()

        for result in query:
            task = Task(result[0], result[1])
            Project.get_project_by_name(project_name).add_task(task)
```

### main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from objects import Project, Task, Entry
from database import KronosDatabase


class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.menu_bar = Menu(parent)

        self.file_menu = Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff=0)
        self.report_menu = Menu(self.menu_bar, tearoff=0)

        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=self.file_menu)
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label='Reporting', menu=self.report_menu)

        parent.config(menu=self.menu_bar)

        self.project_label = ttk.Label(parent, text='Project')
        self.selected_project = StringVar()
        self.project_combobox = ttk.Combobox(parent, textvariable=self.selected_project, state='readonly')
        self.project_combobox['values'] = Project.projects
        self.project_combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self._project_combobox_selection_changed)

        self.task_label = ttk.Label(parent, text='Task')
        self.selected_task = StringVar()
        self.task_combobox = ttk.Combobox(parent, textvariable=self.selected_task, state='readonly')
        self.task_combobox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self._task_combobox_selection_changed)

        self.button = ttk.Button(parent, text='Start', command=self._button_click)
        self.button.state(['disabled'])

        self.time_label = ttk.Label(parent, text='00:00', font='Segoe 16')

        self.project_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=W)
        self.project_combobox.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=W)
        self.task_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=2, pady=2,sticky=W)
        self.task_combobox.grid(row=1, column=1,padx=2, pady=2, sticky=W)
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=2, pady=2,)
        self.time_label.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=2, pady=2,)

    def _project_combobox_selection_changed(self, event):
        self.button.state(['disabled'])
        self.task_combobox.set('')
        self._get_tasks_for_project(self.selected_project.get())

    def _task_combobox_selection_changed(self, event):
        if self.task_combobox.get() != '':
            self.button.state(['!disabled'])

    def _button_click(self):
        if (state):
            self.button.configure(text='Start')
            self._stop_timer()
        else:
            self.button.configure(text='Stop')
            self._start_timer()

    def _get_tasks_for_project(self, project):
        selected_project = Project.get_project_by_name(project)
        db.get_tasks_for_project(self.selected_project.get())
        self.task_combobox['values'] = selected_project.get_tasks()

    def _start_timer(self):
        global state
        state = True
        self.project_combobox.configure(state='disabled')
        self.task_combobox.configure(state='disabled')

    def _stop_timer(self):
        global state
        state = False
        self.project_combobox.configure(state='readonly')
        self.task_combobox.configure(state='readonly')
        self._generate_entry()

    def _generate_entry(self):
        task_id = int(self.selected_task.get().split(':')[0])
        duration = self.time_label.cget('text')

        entry = Entry(task_id, datetime.now().date(), duration)
        db.insert_entry(entry)

    def update_time_label(self):
        if (state):
            global timer

            timer[1] += 1
            if (timer[1] >= 60):
                timer[1] = 0
                timer[0] += 1

            time_string = pattern.format(timer[0], timer[1])
            self.time_label.configure(text=time_string)
        app.after(60000, self.update_time_label)


db = KronosDatabase(u'C:\\Users\\dmolnar004\\Desktop\\kronos.db')
db.get_projects()
pattern = '{0:02d}:{1:02d}'
timer = [0, 0]
state = False

app = Tk()
app.title('Krono/Kairos')
window = MainWindow(app)
window.update_time_label()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix indentation in you **objects.py**, use 4 spaces instead of tabs+spaces

so it will look like this:

```
class Project:
'''Class that holds the projects'''
projects = []

def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.tasks = []
    type(self).projects.append(self)
...
```

You don't need parenthesis here

```
if (task not in self.tasks):
```

Just write

```
if task not in self.tasks:
```

You might want to store projects as dict(project.name: project) instead of list so this:

```
@staticmethod
def get_project_by_name(name):
        for project in Project.projects:
                if name == project.name:
                        return project
```

will be just:

```
@staticmethod
def get_project_by_name(name):
    return Project.projects[name]
```

In case if you will have multiple projects with the same name you can make it dict(project.name: [projects_list])

in **database.py**

I would not keep db connection always open, I would connect to it each time I need it.

then

```
for result in query:
        task = Task(result[0], result[1])
        Project.get_project_by_name(project_name).add_task(task)
```

will be prettier if:

```
for _id, name in query:
    task = Task(_id, name)
    Project.get_project_by_name(project_name).add_task(task)
```

in **main.py**
its not clear why you need state to be a global variable.